# Is there a way to select a subset of an array in Vapor/Fluent?

Tags: postgresql, vapor, vapor-fluent

I have a table in a PostgreSQL database used by a Vapor Swift app.  One of the columns in the table is an array of strings.

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Code" (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT NULL,
    lines text[] NOT NULL
);
```

I'd like to select some rows, pulling only the first four items from the array.  The raw SQL is this:

```
SELECT id, name, lines[1:4] FROM "Code"
```

Is there a way to specify the array subset via Vapor's Fluent syntax?  I would also be happy using a raw SQL query, that can then be decoded by the model (like `alsoDecode` with joins).

This is the model, fwiw:

```swift
struct Snippet: Codable, PostgreSQLUUIDModel {
    var id: UUID?
    var name: String
    var lines: [String]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at SwifQL + Bridges https://github.com/SwifQL

Comment: Thanks, @imike - that looks like an interesting option, and I see the support for psql arrays.  I'm already invested in Fluent though, and was hoping for a solution there.

Comment: This lib support everything cause it is superflexible and you can easily add anything you want if it is missing. And my support 24/7 cause I'm on it every day with real production projects.

Comment: Is there no solution Fluent? I've been stuck on this issue too...